# Get a fresh bash without conda

Tags: python, bash, conda

is there a way to easily switch from conda environments to my system's native python environment? When I have conda activated, and I run `bash` or `exec bash` it doesn't seem to work, and when I run `python` it uses conda's python and it's not using the system python path. The only way I've been able to get this to work is by restarting the terminal entirely. Is there a faster way to do this?

(I've actually removed the conda init block from my ~/.bashrc and I run it manually every time I want to use conda's python.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Just deactivate the `base` environment:

```
(base) $ conda deactivate
$
```

2. Configure your conda to not activate the `base` environment on startup.

```
(base) $ conda config --set auto_activate_base false

<restart shell>

$ 

# use the system python
$ python

# to use conda you'll need to activate it first
$ conda activate
(base) $ python
```

Comment: Thanks! The "--set auto_activate_base false" was exactly what I was missing. This way when I deactivate it actually reverts to the system python.

Answer (score 0):

The conda command you're looking for is `deactivate`.

Suppose you have activated the `myproject` environment.

```bash
$ conda deactivate
```

Now your environment is `base`, as seen by `which python`,
or `conda info --envs`.

```bash
$ conda deactivate
```

Now you're not using conda at all, and `which python` shows the system
interpreter, likely `/usr/bin/python`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit of a hack, but what about adding an alias pointing to the system python before the conda block in .bashrc? Assuming you don't want to use "conda deactivate" and lose the environment completely.

```
alias syspython=`which python`

# >>> conda initalize >>>
...
```

You should then be able to use the system python in a conda env like so:

```
syspython file.py ...
```